# Android - TabLayout - Navigation with RecyclerView Items

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, android-recyclerview

I have a Tabbed Activity with 3 Tabs. On each Tab are RecyclerViews with some list items. If you click on an item a new fragment should open and there should appear a Back-Button in the toolbar. My current screen looks like this:

[image: Current Screen]

And now I will show you my code. At first MainActivity.java with the TabLayout:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Pflege");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.tab_icon_pflege);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.tab_icon_dokumentation);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(R.drawable.tab_icon_probleme);

        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                switch(tab.getPosition()) {
                    case 0:
                        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                        toolbar.setTitle("Pflege");
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                        toolbar.setTitle("Daten");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
                        toolbar.setTitle("Probleme");
                        break;
                    default:
                        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                        toolbar.setTitle("Pflege");
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch(position){
                case 0:
                    Tab1Pflege tab1 = new Tab1Pflege();
                    return tab1;
                case 1:
                    Tab2Dokumentation tab2 = new Tab2Dokumentation();
                    return tab2;
                case 2:
                    Tab3Probleme tab3 = new Tab3Probleme();
                    return tab3;
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "Pflege";
                case 1:
                    return "Daten";
                case 2:
                    return "Probleme";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Fragment for the first tab with the RecyclerView:

```
public class Tab1Pflege extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter rvAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager rvLayoutManager;

    private ArrayList<String> listItems;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1_pflege, container, false);

        listItems = new ArrayList<>();
        listItems.add("Test1");
        listItems.add("Test2");
        listItems.add("Test3");

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        rvLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(rvLayoutManager);
        rvAdapter = new RvAdapter(listItems);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(rvAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }

}
```

And here is my RecyclerView Adapter:

```
public class RvAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RvAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<String> listItems;

    public RvAdapter (ArrayList<String> listItems){
        this.listItems = listItems;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rv_item_layout, null);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.itemTitle.setText(listItems.get(position));
        holder.itemImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_keyboard_arrow_right);


        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                System.out.println(listItems.get(position));
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listItems.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView itemTitle;
        ImageView itemImage;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView){
            super(itemView);

            itemTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemTitle);
            itemImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemImage);
        }

    }
}
```

In this class is an onClickListener for clicking on a list item. And there I want to open a new fragment for example for Test1. On top of that there should appear a Back-Button in the toolbar to navigate back to the Tab1 Overview with the RecyclerView. But I have no idea how to do that. Can someone help me with it?

Comment: If you want to play with fragments then tabs and viewpager of your MainActivity should also be used in fragment so your whole project structure was implemented using FragmentTransaction mode, in current scenario it would be good if you can either show a FragmentDialog or a new activity  and to show backarrow on Toolbar use
       getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
       getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

Answer (score 0):

In `onClick`, you can do something like this (to load another fragment)

```
FragmentTransaction trans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
Fragment fragment = // TODO: initialise your fragment 'fragment'
mFragments.push(fragment);
// Animation, if need it
// trans.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.right_in, R.anim.left_out,
//          R.anim.right_out, R.anim.left_in);

// _container is the id of 'fragment' container in the your xml
trans.replace(R.id._container, fragment);

// variable to identify this fragment, and title of the page as well
String name = // TODO: initialise
trans.addToBackStack(name);
trans.commit();

getSupportActionBar().setTitle(name);
```

and in onCreate of your activity, setup listener for back stack changes.

```
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
manager.addOnBackStackChangedListener(mBackStackListener);
```

and you can change back icon in

```
private OnBackStackChangedListener mBackStackListener = new OnBackStackChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onBackStackChanged() {
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        int count = manager.getBackStackEntryCount();
        if(count > 0) {
            // TODO: Show back icon
        } else {
            // TODO: Other icon
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: How can I call the getSupportFragmentManager() method in the onClick of the RvAdapter class? Because it is a method of the MainAcitvity class isnt it?

Comment: In the MainActivity I have a method "onItemSelected" now with your firsr code part. In the Tab1Pflege.java I put "(MainActivity) getActivity()" to the constructor of the RvAdapter class. And there in the onClickListener I call the "onItemSelected" method from the main activity. The title in the toolbar got changed and the old fragment is going away, but the new fragment is empty. And however when I go on Tab2 it is also empty, but Tab3 not.